# Multithreading in java - 4 threads that do the same automatically

Tags: java, multithreading

I've written a program to scan for amicable numbers (a pair of 2 numbers that the sum of all devisors of one equals to the other) It works ok and I'll include the entire code below.
I tried to get it to run with several threads so I moved the code to a class called Breaker and my main looks as follows:

```
    Breaker line1 = new Breaker("thread1");
    Breaker line2 = new Breaker("thread2");
    Breaker line3 = new Breaker("thread3");
    Breaker line4 = new Breaker("thread4");

    line1.scanRange(1L, 650000L);
    line2.scanRange(650001L, 850000L);
    line3.scanRange(850001L, 1000000L);
    line4.scanRange(1000001L, 1200001L);
```

Now this does shorten the time noticably, but this is not a smart solution and the threads end each on very different times.

What I'm trying to do, is to automate the process so that a master thread that has the entire range, will fire up sections of short ranges (10000) from the master range, and when a thread ends, to fire up the next section in a new thread, until the entire master range is done.

I've tried understanding how to use synchronized, notify() and wait() but after several tries all ended with different errors and unwanted behaviour.

Here is Breaker.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Breaker implements Runnable{

Long from, to = null;
String name = null;
Thread t = new Thread(this);

public Breaker(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void scanRange(Long from, Long to){
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    this.scan();
}

private void scan() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>();
    Long startingTime = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
    Long lastReport = new Long(startingTime);
    System.out.println(startingTime + ": Starting number is: " + this.from);
    for (Long i = this.from; i <= this.to; i++) {
        if (((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) - startingTime ) % 60 == 0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) != lastReport) {
            System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) + ": " + this.name + " DOING NOW " + i.toString() + ".");
            lastReport = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        }
        ArrayList<Long> a = new ArrayList<Long>();
        a = getFriendPair(i);
        if(a != null) {
            results.add(a);
            System.out.println(this.name + ": FOUND PAIR! " + a.toString());
        }
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) + ": " + this.name + " Done. Total pairs found: " + results.size() + 
            ". Total working time: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) - startingTime) + " seconds.");


}

/**
 * Receives integer and returns an array of the integer and the number who is it's
 * pair in case it has any. Else returns null.
 * @param i
 * @return
 */
private static ArrayList<Long> getFriendPair(Long i) {

    Long possibleFriend = getAndSumAllDevisors(i);
    if (possibleFriend.compareTo(i) <= 0) return null;
    Long sumOfPossibleFriend = getAndSumAllDevisors(possibleFriend);
    if(sumOfPossibleFriend.equals(i)) {
        ArrayList<Long> pair = new ArrayList<Long>();
        pair.add(i);
        pair.add(possibleFriend);

        return pair;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Long getAndSumAllDevisors(Long victim) {
    Long sum = new Long(1);
    Long i = 2L;
    Long k = new Long(0);
    while ((k = i * i) <= victim) {
        if ((victim % i) == 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (k == victim) return sum;
            sum += (victim / i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

Comment: Forget wait and notify, learn how to do it with the Fork/Join framework, which is a 100% match for this case.

Comment: funny indeed, where are your threads.

Comment: I'm starting the threads from the Breaker itself (note for line 7 and line 16 in Breaker). again, not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: @Tom it is ok, but not very common. "Common" is `Thread line1 = new Thread(new Breaker("thread1",1,650000L)); line1.start();`. It is a question of style ...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik , I'm reading about it now and I'll probably go with that. If you can elaborate it slightly in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking none of the answers but rather Marko's comment and implemented my solution using a [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework. It works and runs almost at twice the speed of the none optimized version.

My code looks now like so:

**main file (runner)**

```
public class runner {

private static Long START_NUM = 1L;
private static Long END_NUM =   10000000L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long preciseStartingTime = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis());

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    WorkManager worker = new WorkManager(START_NUM, END_NUM);
    pool.invoke(worker);

    System.out.println("precise time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - preciseStartingTime));
}
```

**WorkManager**

I've defined here 3 class variables. `from` and `to` are set from a constructor which is called from the main file. And `threshold` which is the maximum amount of numbers the program will assign a single thread to compute serially.
As you can see in the code, it will recursively make the range smaller until it is small enough to to compute directly, then it calls Breaker to start breaking.

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class WorkManager extends RecursiveAction{

Long from, to;
Long threshold = 10000L;

public WorkManager(Long from, Long to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

protected void computeDirectly(){
    Breaker b = new Breaker(from, to);
    b.scan();
}

@Override
protected void compute() {
    if ((to - from) <= threshold){
        System.out.println("New thread from " + from + " to " + to);
        computeDirectly();
    }
    else{
        Long split = (to - from) /2;
        invokeAll(new WorkManager(from, from + split),
                new WorkManager(from + split + 1L, to));
    }
}
}
```

**Breaker** (is no longer an implementation of of Runnable)

```
public class Breaker{

Long from, to = null;

public Breaker(Long lFrom, Long lTo) {
    this.from = lFrom;
    this.to   = lTo;
}

public void scan() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>();
    Long startingTime = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
    for (Long i = this.from; i <= this.to; i++) {
        ArrayList<Long> a = new ArrayList<Long>();
        a = getFriendPair(i);
        if(a != null) {
            results.add(a);
            System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) + ": FOUND PAIR! " + a.toString());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Receives integer and returns an array of the integer and the number who is it's
 * pair in case it has any. Else returns null.
 * @param i
 * @return
 */
private static ArrayList<Long> getFriendPair(Long i) {

    Long possibleFriend = getAndSumAllDevisors(i);
    if (possibleFriend.compareTo(i) <= 0) return null;
    Long sumOfPossibleFriend = getAndSumAllDevisors(possibleFriend);
    if(sumOfPossibleFriend.equals(i)) {
        ArrayList<Long> pair = new ArrayList<Long>();
        pair.add(i);
        pair.add(possibleFriend);

        return pair;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Long getAndSumAllDevisors(Long victim) {
    Long sum = new Long(1);
    Long i = 2L;
    Long k = new Long(0);
    while ((k = i * i) <= victim) {
        if ((victim % i) == 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (k == victim) return sum;
            sum += (victim / i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider ExecutorService, which is backed by a thread pool.  You feed it tasks and they get shuffled off to worker threads as they become available:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "Fixed Thread Pool". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with a fixed thread pool size. Your master thread can either feed directly to the executor service or you can disconnect them via a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). The Java Doc of the blocking queue describes the producer-consumer pattern quite nicely.